# Handle Multiple Intents in single Utterance in LUIS

Tags: nlp, azure-language-understanding

I need to handle multiple Intents in single Utterance in Luis. For example, there is an Intent called "Order" and i have configured that with Utterance below.

**I want 2 pizza from Dominos and 2 bucket chicken from abc and xyz.**

In the above Utterance there is 2 different orders i need to track.

1) 2 pizza from Dominos

where the Entitees are:
**Quantity** - 2,
**Dish** - Pizza,
**Store** - Dominos

2) 2 bucket chicken from KFC

where the Entitees are

**Quantity** - 2,
**Dish** - bucket chicken,
**Store** - abc and xyz

**abc and xyz** is the Store name and its a single store (store name itself contains and like Larson & toubro).

How can i handle this in LUIS? How can we handle same entitees multiple times in single utterance? Anyother NLP supports this thing?.

Can someone guide me on this?

Comment: What have you tried so far in LUIS?

Answer (score 0):

With the example you provided, it looks like there is only one intent and that is Order. The user might order different items from different stores. So basically your utterances follow a pattern:

1. Buy x from b
2. Buy x,y,z from store a
3. Buy x from a and y from b
   You can train your LUIS app with possible [patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/LUIS/luis-how-to-model-intent-pattern) to achieve more accuracy.

At the API endpoint you can check for entities do the following:

1. If there is only one entity of type item and one entity of type store then its type 1.
2. If there are multiple entities of type items and only one entity of
   store then its type 2.
3. If there are multiple entities of type item and multiple entities of type store then type 3.

Its pretty much easy to get the store and items to order in the first 2 types. For the third type you can make use of the [startIndex and endIndex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-get-started-cs-get-intent#understand-what-luis-returns) property of entity returned by LUIS. You can group item entity with store entity checking the index values i.e Buy x from a and y from b so x is the first item encountered and so the store a so map item x with store a.

PS: This ain't the best approach, I'll update you if I get a better way out.